# Define an array of mixed types in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays

I'm putting together a little C# project - I am rewriting something I had written in JavaScript as C#.

Part of my project requires an array of arrays with mixed content in. In JavaScript I just initiate the array:

```
Log: []
```

then use push:

```
Log.push(logEntry);
```

Where logEntry is:

```
string, string, string, int, int, int
```

The ints may also be empty.

The purpose of this is to store data before JSON encoding it and sending it to a web API on another server.

Can someone point me in the right direction to do this in C#, as all the answers I find seem to want to only store the same type of data.

Thanks in advance,

Tony.

Comment: `List<Object>` is a good way or `List<dynamic>` is another.

Answer (score 6):

### Here is how you can do it

Use `List<object>` (as everything is derived from object in C#):

```
var list = new List<object>();
list.Add(123);
list.Add("Hello World");
```

---

Also `dynamic` might work for you (and your javascript background)

```
var list = new List<dynamic>();
list.Add(123);
list.Add(new
{
    Name = "Lorem Ipsum"
});
```

If you wan't to use `dynamic` you really need to know what you're doing. Please read this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) before you start.

### But do you need it?

C# is a strongly-typed and very solid programming language. It is very flexible and great for building apps using object-oriented and functional paradigms. What you want to do may be fine for javascript, but looks a bit ugly with C#. My recommendation is: use object oriented programming and try to build models for your problem. Never mix types together like you tried. One list is for a single data-type.

Comment: Beat me to it by seconds. This is what I would use. Everything derives from `System.Object`

Comment: So do I do list.Add for each new array in the array? Like list.Add(new{string, string, string, int, int, int}) - where string and int would obviously be replaced with the actual values.

Comment: @TonyMerryfield if you need to add an array to a list use `list.AddRange(array)`. Please note: the last example is adding an object to list and not array.

Comment: @AndreiM - the purpose of this is to build a data set for use in a web service. The array will eventually get JSON encoded and sent to and API. I'll give the example above a go and see how it works out :)

Comment: @TonyMerryfield could you tell me more about your data set?

Comment: needed when passing objects via JS interops

Answer (score 2):

1. You can try using the `ArrayList` class.
2. Another way for a heterogeneous collection of objects is to use `List<Object>`

The `ArrayList` class is designed to hold collections of objects. The objects can be of different Type. However, it does not always offer the best performance.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The ArrayList class is designed to hold heterogeneous collections of
>   objects. However, it does not always offer the best performance.
>   Instead, we recommend the following:
>
> For a heterogeneous collection of objects, use the List (in
>   C#) or List(Of Object) (in Visual Basic) type.
>
> For a homogeneous collection of objects, use the List class.